Proxy server is not working with VPN in android
I am trying to create a proxy server in android that I can use to share my VPN connection with other devices connected to the same network. So one device has a VPN connection and others can connect to it through proxy server and use internet through VPN.
I have tried multiple solutions that are either working without VPN OR with both devices connected to the same VPN(that kills the use case). But when I start VPN on my device and then start proxy server and connect the child device through the proxy, the normal internet traffic stops working. However, apps like Whatsapp can still send/receive calls and messages but normal chrome browsing or youtube and insta don't work on the proxy client device.
I know that it is possible to do it as an older now deprecated version of my app provided this functionality and currently Every Proxy app is providing this functionality but to a limited VPNs. Which is why I need to make it for my own Wireguard based VPN as it does not work with Every Proxy app.
In my code I am trying to build a transparent HTTP proxy with a Connect Tunnel that doesn't need any certificates and does not intercept/block any traffic.
Currently my code is following:
public class ConnectProxy {
    private final int port;
    private volatile boolean isRunning = false;
    private Thread serverThread;

    public ConnectProxy(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (isRunning) {
            log("Server is already running.");
            return; // Avoid starting multiple instances
        }

        isRunning = true;
        serverThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port,50, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"))) {
                log("Proxy Server running on port " + port);

                while (isRunning) {
                    try {
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        new Thread(() -> handleClient(clientSocket)).start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        if (isRunning) {
                            log("Error accepting client connection: " + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Server error: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        serverThread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (!isRunning) {
            log("Server is already stopped.");
            return;
        }

        isRunning = false;
        if (serverThread != null && !serverThread.isInterrupted()) {
            serverThread.interrupt();
        }
        log("Proxy Server stopped.");
    }

    private void handleClient(Socket clientSocket) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
             OutputStream clientOut = clientSocket.getOutputStream()) {

            String requestLine = reader.readLine();
            if (requestLine == null || !requestLine.startsWith("CONNECT")) {
                clientOut.write("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                log("Invalid request from client.");
                return;
            }

            String[] parts = requestLine.split(" ");
            String[] hostPort = parts[1].split(":");
            String host = hostPort[0];
            int port = Integer.parseInt(hostPort[1]);

            log("Connection request for: " + host + ":" + port);

            try (Socket targetSocket = new Socket(host, port)) {
                clientOut.write("HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                clientOut.flush();

                InputStream targetIn = targetSocket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream targetOut = targetSocket.getOutputStream();

                DataTracker tracker = new DataTracker();

                Thread clientToServer = new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        relayData(clientSocket.getInputStream(), targetOut, tracker, true);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log("Error relaying client to server data: " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                Thread serverToClient = new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        relayData(targetIn, clientOut, tracker, false);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log("Error relaying server to client data: " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

                clientToServer.start();
                serverToClient.start();

                clientToServer.join();
                serverToClient.join();

                log(String.format("Data for %s:%d - Uploaded: %.2f KB, Downloaded: %.2f KB",
                        host, port, tracker.uploaded / 1024.0, tracker.downloaded / 1024.0));
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                log("Error handling connection to: " + host + ":" + port + " - " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log("Error handling client: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void relayData(InputStream input, OutputStream output, DataTracker tracker, boolean isUpload) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                output.flush();

                if (isUpload) {
                    tracker.uploaded += bytesRead;
                } else {
                    tracker.downloaded += bytesRead;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log("Connection closed during data relay: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void log(String message) {
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        System.out.println("[" + timestamp + "] " + message);
    }

    private static class DataTracker {
        long uploaded = 0;
        long downloaded = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectProxy proxy = new ConnectProxy(8888);
        proxy.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(proxy::stop));
    }
}


